# Microsoft.Internal.Assumes+InternalErrorException: Internal error occurred

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have been encountering this error while trying to load Visual studio 2012, An exception has been encountered.This may be caused by an extension and was given a location for additional information in  `C:\Users\~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml`    and in checking the location I have the following as error I clearly don't understand it:

```
 Microsoft.Internal.Assumes+InternalErrorException: Internal error occurred. 
Additional information: ''. at    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.InPrerequisiteLoop() at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part) at 

System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports) at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part) at 
    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition) at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart) at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore() at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value() at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export) at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.<CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfTM>b__1() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at 
System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InvokeMatchingFactories[TExtensionInstance,TExtensionFactory,TMetadataView](IEnumerable`1 lazyFactories, Func`2 getter,IContentType dataContentType, Object errorSource)
```

has anyone ever encountered this error?

Comment: If any of the answers helped, please accept as answer and let's close this question. :)

Answer (score 7):

Remove all entries under these
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon
HKEY_CURRENTUSER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio
_
Upon restarting Visual Studio, it ran me through the 'first time' processes, which means my user profile was completely reset. That resolved my issues.

I too had this problem and took 1 week+ to find out this solution for the problem... :)

Comment: Thanks you, Its works, remove specific version folder for VS 2012 => VisualStudio\11.0 ,VisualStudio\11.0_Config, VSCommon\11.0

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error before as well. In Visual Studio, try going to *TOOLS* then *Extensions and Updates...* and check to see if you need any updates. That worked for me.

Also check out this thread on one of the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48132a7a-ced1-4e56-880c-7ad06dc49a64/im-getting-a-microsoftinternalassumesinternalerrorexception-on-vs-with-perfectly-valid-code). The guy asking the question said he solved this problem by re-installing VS 2012 Update 1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple repair of Visual Studio fixed my issue.